# symfony2 two one-to-one relations in @ORM/Id field

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-one, database-relations

I have three entities: 'Usuario', 'Estudiante' and 'Administrador'. 'Usuario' represents the users in the application, that can be 'Estudiante' or 'Administrador'. How can I relate this?

I show you the three entities:

Entity 'Usuario'

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields = {"id_usuario", "guid"})
*/
class Usuario
{

/**
 *  @ORM\Id
 *  @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Estudiante", inversedBy="id_estudiante")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id_usuario")
 *  @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Administrador", inversedBy="id_administrador")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id_usuario")
 **/
protected $id_usuario;

/**
 *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
protected $guid;
```

(...)

Entity 'Estudiante'

```
class Estudiante implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     *  @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, indica tu email")
     *  @Assert\Email(message = "El email introducido no es válido",
     *                checkMX=true)
     **/
    protected $id_estudiante;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *  @Assert\Length(min=4, max=8, minMessage = "La contraseña debe contener entre 6 y 12 caracteres", maxMessage = "La contraseña debe contener entre 6 y 12 caracteres")
    */
    protected $password;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $salt;

(...)
```

Entity 'Administrador'

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity(fields = {"id_estudiante", "guid"})
*/
class Administrador implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     *  @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     *  @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Por favor, indica tu email")
     *  @Assert\Email(message = "El email introducido no es válido",
     *                checkMX=true)
     **/
    protected $id_administrador;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *  @Assert\Length(min=4, max=8, minMessage = "La contraseña debe contener entre 6 y 12 caracteres", maxMessage = "La contraseña debe contener entre 6 y 12 caracteres")
    */
    protected $password;

    /**
     *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $salt;

(...)
```

Please, how can I do that?
I need to separate 'Estudiante' and 'Administrador' because if someone is registered as an 'Estudiante' and later wants to became an 'Administrador', I only have to move the field from 'Administrador' to 'Estudiante'. So another questions would be... is there another way to do that change?

Answer (score 0):

First you should take a look how you want design your database, as far as I see you should not add different passwords/salts for each of the entities - under prediction that users also have password field.

**General Advise**
I strongly advise you should take a look on Data Normalization and may look on some different existing data models.

Take a look here:

- [Normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)
- [Further reading on real examplse: Industry Approaches](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/)

**Step 1 - Design**

I would go for a different approach as and see `Usuario`, `Estudiante` and `Administrador` as userType/UserGroups. This could look like this. [image: Sample DB Design (quickdirty!)] There would be three rows in your `userType` Table - (`Usuario`, `Estudiante` and `Administrador`).

The question you should ask yourself is if you want to have a user a `oneToMany` or a `oneToOne` Relation.
In case of last, a `oneToOne` relation would mean that a a users can only be only **one** userType which would mean my proposed would work. Another extensive example would be this link and picture below (for ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/user-system-database-design):  [image: User System Database Design from a Q&A]

If you want a `oneToMany` relation you can just add a field user_id to the userType table which would be mapped to users. This would give you the opportunity of using different userTypes at the same time.

**Step 2 - Creating the right Entities**

Additionally take a look on the Doctrine Project (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) for knowing how and when to use the right statements.

Hope this sheds lingt into the dark and good luck on your endeavors!

Comment: Hi @s1x, first of all, thanks for your answer. I think I have not explained correctly how the entities are relationed. There are only two user types: 'Estudiante' and 'Administrador'. Both have many common fields, that's why I create the 'Usuario' entity. So this entity, must have a relation either with 'Estudiante' or 'Administrador' entity. Also, I need to separate 'Estudiante' and 'Administrador' in two different entities to add the getRoles() method in each one. For 'Estudiante' it will return "array('ROLE_ESTUDIANTE');" and for 'Administrador' it will return "array('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR');"

Comment: Regarding the information you provided you still use users as main table where the basic information will be stored. Why you don't use groups/types for your database design? Think about it for a moment. In case of your getRoles() you can still use this later via the User Entity if you connect them via a relation. In case of PHP just define a getRoles() in your user class and use the both entities/repros to recieve the data and get the job done.

Comment: I have tried to define a class Role that implements RoleInterface, but it causes problems with php 5.4 and 5.5. Can you write an example of how assinging different roles to an User? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle take a look here espc. on the `/model` and `/controller` folders. A good overview about the Doctrine Config files you'll find here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/tree/master/Resources/config/doctrine/model

Comment: I have taken a look at this bundle but I don't understand how to solve my problem with it. What I need is to add/detele roles to an user created with an entity that implements UserInterface.